# Why add/remove method was called automatically when NSArrayController binds to an array?

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, kvc

I'm trying to understand how NSArrayController works...

- When I create an NSMutableArray "employeeArray" to hold "Person" object.
  [image]
- I use NSArrayController in GUI and bind with the "employeeArray".
  [image]
- I add two buttons for adding and removing "Person" objects in "employeeArray". Both buttons are binded with the received action "add:" and "remove:" of NSArrayController.
  [image]
- Inorder to do something else when adding/removing "Person" objects in "employeeArray", I add two methods:

  - (void)insertObject:(Person *)p inEmployeeArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
  - (void)removeObjectFromEmployeeArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

**Question:**

1. I didn't do anything(write any code) to let NSArrayController know the two methods above, why they are called automatically when I click the add/remove button? What happened?
2. What add/remove method does NSArrayController use?
3. Does NSArrayController smart enough to recognized those methods? What if I modified the method names randomly, will it be called correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally understand:

By following "[Key-Value Coding Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html) Patterns". NSArrayController is smart enough to recognize the "insert" "remove" methods automatically.

If you alter the method name without following the accessor pattern. It will not work.